# NodePort, LoadBalance Services - What happens with Routing?

Tags: kubernetes

The k8s docs aren't very clear what happens with routing when using the different service types, leading me to a series of questions:

To help the question, assume the following cluster setup:

- 3 Nodes: `N_a`, `N_b`, `N_c`
- 1 Service: `S_1`
- 2 Pods: `P_x1`, `P_x2` that are part of the service `S_1`
- `P_x1` is running on `N_a`
- `P_x2` is running on `N_b`

1) When using a `NodePort` for `S_1` using port `x`, do ALL nodes in a cluster make the service available on port `x`? OR do ONLY the nodes running the pods that make up the service make the service available on port `x`? So in both scenarios, `N_a` and `N_b` will make `S_1` available on port `x`, but can I hit `N_c` on port `x`?

2) Using `NodePort` for `S_1` still, if I hit `N_a` on port `x`, will I only be routed to `P_x1` (e.g., the pods for that service running locally on the Node), or may I be routed to `P_x2`, so off the Node and over the network again?

3) If I run `S_1` as a `LoadBalanced` service, will the load-balancer provisioned only route requests to `N_a` and `N_b`? With those requests when hitting `N_a` and `N_b` only being routed to pods `P_x1` and `P_x2` respectively? So one hop over the network, or will it talk to all three nodes and rely on them each doing a second level of routing/load-balancing? (Which seems quite inefficient).

4) Does the `Ingress` controller function any differently for routing (other than being L7 rather than L4) than a `LoadBalanced` service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes. NodePort opens a port on all worker nodes. When you create a Service, an iptables rule is created on all worker nodes. When a pod on any node accesses this Service's IP, the iptables rule on the physical node where the pod resides will redirect its packets accordingly.

2) Both. A Service does WRR load-balancing across all the associated pods.

3) I do bare-metal deployments so I can't answer this qn.

4) Afaik, Ingress is a replacement to the LoadBalancer. Instead of depending on the cloud provider's reverse proxy, you deploy your own Ingress that runs in the k8s cluster.